# Some Strange Fault (In My Model Record ?)

Tags: elm

My compiler complains about two values:

`model.firstChord.fifth` and `model.secondChord.fifth`

in this excerpt:

```
-- render frets
renderFret : Model -> Fret -> Html Msg
renderFret model fret =
    let
        ( pitchName, pitchLevel ) = fret.pitch
        ( firstChordRootPitchName, firstChordRootPitchLevel ) = model.firstChord.root
        ( firstChordThirdPitchName, firstChordThirdPitchLevel ) = model.firstChord.third
        ( firstChordFifthPitchName, firstChordFifthPitchLevel ) = model.firstChord.fifth
        ( secondChordRootPitchName, secondChordRootPitchLevel ) = model.secondChord.root
        ( secondChordThirdPitchName, secondChordThirdPitchLevel ) = model.secondChord.third
        ( secondChordFifthPitchName, secondChordFifthPitchLevel ) = model.secondChord.fifth
    in
        ...
```

it tells me:

> `model.firstChord` does not have a field named `fifth`. - The type of `model.firstChord` is:
>
> Maybe Chord
>
> Which does not contain a field named `fifth`.

but my model has a field `fifth`:

```
-- initial model
init : ( Model, Cmd Msg )
init =
    (
        {   firstChord =
            Just
            {   root = ( "C", 3 )
            ,   third = ( "E", 3 )
            ,   fifth = ( "G", 3 )
            }
        ,   secondChord =
            Just
            {   root = ( "F", 3 )
            ,   third = ( "A", 3 )
            ,   fifth = ( "C", 4 )
            }
        }
    ,
        Cmd.none
    )
```

The type of the chord is:

```
-- chords
type alias Chord =
    {   root : Pitch
    ,   third : Pitch
    ,   fifth : Pitch
    }
```

Each pitch has this type:

```
-- pitch
type alias Pitch = ( PitchName, PitchLevel )

-- pitch name
type alias PitchName = String

-- pitch level
type alias PitchLevel = Int
```

Where could be the problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compile error says exactly what the problem is

`Maybe Chord` is either `Just Chord` or `Nothing`. None of these two contain a field named `fifth`.

In order to make this work you need to make sure that `model.firstChord` and `model.secondChord` are `Just Chord`:

```
-- render frets
renderFret : Model -> Fret -> Html Msg
renderFret model fret =
    case (model.firstChord, model.secondChord) of
        (Just firstChord, Just secondChord) ->                
            let
                ( pitchName, pitchLevel ) = fret.pitch
                ( firstChordRootPitchName, firstChordRootPitchLevel ) = firstChord.root
                ( firstChordThirdPitchName, firstChordThirdPitchLevel ) = firstChord.third
                ( firstChordFifthPitchName, firstChordFifthPitchLevel ) = firstChord.fifth
                ( secondChordRootPitchName, secondChordRootPitchLevel ) = secondChord.root
                ( secondChordThirdPitchName, secondChordThirdPitchLevel ) = secondChord.third
                ( secondChordFifthPitchName, secondChordFifthPitchLevel ) = model.secondChord.fifth
            in
                ...
        _ ->
            -- here is something when either `model.firstChord` or `model.secondChord` is `Nothing`
```

By using pattern matching `(Just firstChord, Just secondChord)`, `firstChord` and `secondChord` expressions appear to be of type `Chord`, which has a field named `fifth`

Comment: are you sure it's `let` following `case` ??

Comment: `It looks like the keyword case is being used as a variable. - Rename it to something else` ... this is the message.

Comment: maybe you could help me with the problem that results from your answer, I'll post you a link. BUT FIRST: thanks.

Comment: do you still have compilation errors, when you've modified your code according to my example?

Answer (score 0):

You have not provied your `Model`, but in your init function you have declared the chord as a Maybe. If the compiler was happy with that, then it means your model also includes the `Maybe`s. As a first solution, remove the `Just`s, but also look at your Model

```
init =
    (
        {   firstChord =
            Just
            {   root = ( "C", 3 )
            ,   third = ( "E", 3 )
            ,   fifth = ( "G", 3 )
            }
        ,   secondChord =
            Just   <-------- Here you say that secondChord is Maybe Chord
            {   root = ( "F", 3 )
            ,   third = ( "A", 3 )
            ,   fifth = ( "C", 4 )
            }
        }
    ,
        Cmd.none
    )
```